# Simple power amplifier biasing calculations

Tags: power, amplifier, simulation, proteus

I’m trying to simulate that amplifier from Proteus!

[image]

First I found quiescent current for Q1, Q2 transistors: IcQ = (12 – 0.7)/R1 = 35mA

But to set that current through R1-D1-D2-CE(Q3)-R5 I need the proper biasing of BC184.
How I can calculate the R2 and R6 for that proper bias?
I have the BC184 datasheet:
http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/50719/FAIRCHILD/BC184.html
And know that UR1 = 11,2V and UcQ3 = 11,2V
From datasheet I may found the hfe of BC184 but there is no minimal hfe for Uce = 11,2V what value I need to choose?

That schema may have a very big output DC voltage and the very little changes in base voltage divider resistors changes output DC dramatically. What I must do to tune the output voltage correctly?

Answer (score 1):

First, please put proper DC supplies on your simulation.

Since the push/pull output stage has a unity gain, the DC level on Q3's collector, \$V_{C_{Q3}}\$, will be seen on **VOUT** node as \$V_{OUT}=V_{C_{Q3}}+V_{BE_{Q2}}\$ -neglecting the drop on 0R1 resistor.

In order to set VOUT node to the midpoint of ±12V, which is 0VDC, your first aim should be setting \$V_{C_{Q3}}\$ to about -0.6VDC.

Also, the common emitter amplifier formed by Q3-R1-R2-R5-R6 has a gain of R1/R5 and equals the total gain of the whole amplifier circuit.

- Quiescent current for biasing diodes can be anything between 2-10mA. Let's select 5mA.
- Gain is \$K_v=R1/R5\$ and input voltage is 70mVrms = 0.1Vp. Since the peak value of output signal can be VCC=12V before clipping, \$K_{v(max)}= 12 / 0.1=120\$ for unclipped maximum swing --not necessary to set that high though.

**Example:**

Let's set the gain to 2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHBFN6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So \$R1/R5=2\$. In order to have -0.6VDC on collector of Q3, voltage drop on R1 should be \$V_{R1}=(+12V - (-0.6V) - 1.2V)=11.4VDC\$. Let's select \$I_{bias}=5mA\$, so \$R1=11.4V/5mA=2.2k\$ so R5 will be 1k1. Since the voltage drop on R5 will be \$V_{R5}=1.1k \cdot 5mA = 5.5V\$, the voltage on the base node of Q3 should be \$V_B=-12 + (5.5 + 0.6) = -5.9V\$. For this purpose, I chose R2=33k and R6=12k.

According to simulation results, quiescent output DC level is 0.3VDC which is tolerable. If you set R1 = 5k1 and R5 = 2k5 then the quiescent DC output on VOUT node will be less than 0.1VDC, but the current passing through the biasing diodes will be reduced to about 2.5mA which is fairly enough.

If we select \$K_v=10\$ and \$I_{bias}=2mA\$ then we can find that *(with the calculations above)* R1=5k6, R5=560R, R2=33k and R6=2k7.

You can tune the circuit according to your gain needs.

Comment: I see that maximum diode current is 10mA, but in original scheme its 35mA and the schema positioned as working. May be current through the diode more than 10mA?
Why Kv(max) = 170?
May you show the calculation of all resistors which values you write?

Comment: I don’t fully understand transistor biasing with two power sources! To fully understand how I can calculate resistors values share your calculations for bias resistors for BC184!

Comment: Ooops, Kv(max)=120, not 170. Sorry --- anyway, I've edited my post.

Comment: How you choose R5 value? The voltage drop on R5 may not be founded as for R1!

Comment: @MaxMil please read the post carefully. R5 can be selected from required/selected gain, Kv = R1/R5. If you select Kv=2 then R5=R1/2. If you select Kv=10 then R5=R1/10. That's it.

Comment: ok I'll try all your comments!

Comment: How I can find what current through Q3 CE is enough to drive the output stage? And may the output stage shunt the bias network in Q3 collector?

Comment: Depends on the output transistors and your required output current. Check the output transistor's \$\beta\$ at your required current level. So the bias current for diodes should be at least that level. Suppose you want 1A output current and \$\beta = 40\$. So the minimum bias current should be more than 1A/40 = 25mA. You can select 1.5 times of this value, 38mA. But note that for that level of bias current, you must select very small resistors for previous stage *(e.g. R1=330R)*. Instead, I personally recommend you to make darlington output stage, so you can keep the bias currents small.

Comment: I read much info about how to choose transistor voltage divider resistors. May you write your approach from which you found R2 and R6 value using the BC184 datasheet document from my message?

Comment: You write that R5 value may be founded through Kv! But I know that it’s only for schema without load resistance but in my case the load is the output stage! Or it’s not actual because of output stage is an emitter follower with big input resistance which allow to neglect their resistance. Right?

Comment: How to found the transistor betta for CE voltage and Ic that there is no in datasheet? For example for Uce = 10V and Ic=10mA the value exists but me need the betta for Uce=20V and Ic=30mA

Comment: @MaxMil For your first question: Actually, in our calculations, we neglected the load but we shouldn't have done it that way, because the load needs high current. If the load does not need high current then it can be neglected. The first stage is biased with constant current (thanks to the unbypassed emitter resistor). Since its output is taken from the transistor's collector which has a high output resistance (Rout = R1), the first stage does not allow you to draw high current such as tens of miliamperes. That's why I suggest you to use darlington output stage.

Comment: @MaxMil For your 2nd Q: Simply, you can't. I think you're asking it for calculating required base current and base divider resistors. Transistors have a huge \$\beta\$ margin from one transistor to another --even with same brand/model *(The value you saw in the datasheets are measured on a few transistors and that values are "minimum" or "maximum")*. The only thing you can do is to select collector current, check minimum \$\beta\$ from datasheet and calculate the resistors so that required minimum base current can pass. Thanks to the emitter resistor, transistor can adjust its base current.

Comment: i. e. I need to use minimal betta from datasheet! But minimal for what current or minimal from al that listed in datasheet?

Comment: And I found that used in schema TIP31/TIP32 bjt's are already darlington. May I give them tens of mA's?

Comment: 1) What is minimum \$\beta\$ for BC184? Let's say, 300. What collector/load current do you need? Let's say, 35mA. So, what is minimum required base current? 35000uA/300=117uA. Select base divider resistors so that at least 117uA base current can pass through. 2) TIP31/32s are not darlington, IMO. Where did you see that info? If they were darlington, \$\beta\$ should be high, but it's not. It's about 30.

Comment: That info is here: http://semihow.com/product/data/TIP31,31A,31B,31C_datasheet.pdf

Question, if the base current 117uA, how much the resistor divider current I must to take 10*Base_Current or 5*Base_Current?

Comment: @MaxMil Thevenin equivalent will help you on this. Just think: Some current will pass through bottom resistor, some current will pass through base, and the sum of these will pass through upper resistor. With this info, you can calculate.